# Singleton with Lock - possible deadlock? in java

Tags: java, singleton, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I use singleton to record all events occuring simoultanously in the system.

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Lock dbLock;
  protected Singleton() {}
  private static class SingletonHolder { 
      private final static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
  }
  public static Singleton getInstance() {
      return SingletonHolder.instance;
  }
  public void recordEvent(Event ev) {
       dbLock.lock();
    try {
          database.insert(ev);
        } finally {
         dbLock.unlock();
    }
  }
  public File lockAndGetDB() {
      dbLock.lock();
      return database.getFile();
  }
  public void unlockDB() {
      dbLock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Every few hours I want to lock recording event to send database over internet.

```
file = Singleton.getInstance().lockAndGetDB();
try {
  sendViaHTTP(file);
}
finally {
   Singleton.getInstance().unlock();
}
```

Is there any possible deadlocks? Is it thread safe?

EDITED. (try/finally added for sending viaHTTP) But this is not the main problem. The question is, if there are threads waiting on dbLock.lock(); at recordEvent(Event ev) are my Singleton.getInstance().unlock(); will be able to enter getInstance() code and unlock?

Comment: Implementing a lock like that is going to have a huge impact on this application's performance... is there any reason you don't want to use JDBC?

Comment: @JordanDenison I'm implementing it in Android. But it is general question about java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not, yes there can be deadlocks. What happens if an error occurs during `database.getFile` or `sendViaHTTP`? There is no `try/finally` pattern to ensure `Lock.unlock` is called.

Comment: This is mistake of example, I tried to make it simplier. Yes of course there are try/finally when I'm sending viaHTTP. But it's not the point.

Comment: It's impossible to acquire Lock and not also do database.getFile. For your current implementation, perhaps that operation can never fail. Still, it occurs between the `lock` and the `try` so I imagine a code analyzer like `FindBugs` will rightfully complain.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks arise when you acquire locks in different orders. As there is only one actual lock here, the question does not arise.

Your case looks more like a candidate for a read-write lock to me: use read locks to allow maximal concurrency of DBMS operations, and a write lock when you want them to stop and send the file.

Comment: Deadlocks can also arise when a lock is acquired but never released. What you describe is only one form of deadlock.

Comment: @TimBender No. That's not a deadlock. That's just a lock. A deadlock is a circular chain of processes, each holding a resource that the next one wants.

Comment: Eh, if a thread crashes before releasing the lock and other threads are waiting, are they not halted? Most people would considered that deadlocked.

Comment: @TimBender They might indeed, but they would be wrong. It's just a lock.

Comment: @TimBender That's what I'm doing. Merriam-Webster says 'deadlock: a state of inaction or neutralization resulting from the opposition of equally powerful uncompromising persons or factions'. I don't know what the OP intended, any more than you do, but I do know what the words he used mean. It is to be assumed that he used them correctly until shown otherwise.